# UICollectionViewCells not appearing in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

As the title suggests I have a `UICollectionView` that is hooked up to a `UIViewController` through IB. I have a `UICollectionView` subclass called `imageCell`. In the viewcontroller `viewDidLoad` method, I register the class like this:

```
CGRect collectionViewRect = CGRectMake(384, 60, 728, 924);
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
imageCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:collectionViewRect collectionViewLayout:flow];
[imageCollectionView registerClass:[imageCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
imageCollectionView.delegate = self;
imageCollectionView.dataSource = self;
```

I then call a method called `getPhotos` in `viewDidAppear` (for UI reasons) that gets photos from a service and then I call `[imagCcollectionView reloadData];` inside `getPhotos`.

Then in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I do the following:

```
imageCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
GRKAlbum *album = [albums objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
cell.titleLabel.text = album.name;
return cell;
```

I know I am not doing anything wrong here because the method is being called and `cell` is not `nil` and neither is `album`.

So, when I run all of this code, the `UICollectionView` appears, but nothing is in it. All I can see is the background color of the `collectionView`. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I did NOT create an XIB for the `imageCell` class when I made it and I am using Storyboards.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

There are some ways to debug this situation.

1. Register **UICollectionViewCell** class instead of your **customCell** and set the cell's background color in `cellForItem...`
2. If the cells are appearing in step one try to use your own cell class and set its background

**Are you using storyboard? then..**

You dont have to register any cell for the collection view. You can use the prototype cell, just give the proper id for the cell.You can design everything in your prototype cell. Custom class may not be needed in all the cases.

Comment: thanks a lot.. it's very useful solution.
i just removed 
[self.collectionView registerClass:[cutomCollectionCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cutomCollectionCell"];

and wow, it's working fine.

Comment: This problem had bothered me for half a day. Can't believe it is so simple to solve. I hope next version of XCode would at least show some warnings if they think registerClass is unnecessary or misbehaviour for storyboard.

Comment: Removing `registerClass` part helped me too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's an old saying in China: teach a man how to fish rather than giving him the fish :)

Comment: Remember to implement the numberOfSectionsInCollectionView and collectionView methods if you are also using a custom CollectionViewController class.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "no need to create custom class for the cell"? I'm trying to replicate an iMessage like collection view but idk how you'd edit each individual bubble using only the prototype

Comment: @ScriptKitty ya my statement is little confusing. Custom class is not need in all cases like if you are doing as prototype cell in storyboard and you dont have much to customise. Its good to have a custom class for better accessing the cell properties else you could access via `viewWithTag`

Comment: @AnilVarghese, bro could you help me to take a look at my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45074376/uicollection-view-inside-table-cell-does-not-show-images-in-swift-3 ?

Answer (score 45):

If you created the cell in the storyboard, then just remove the register class statement. You don't need to register anything (for a collection view or table view) if you make the cell in a storyboard (in fact, it screws things up if you do so). The only thing you need to do is make sure that you set the identifier in IB.

Comment: RegisterClass: screwed me though. :( :)

Comment: This fixed it for me. Anyone knowledgeable enough to know why it not only doesn't work like this, but completely screws it up?

Comment: you're always my hero, @rdelmar!  I actually had no idea about this. I happened to leave in the now default example code that has the "register" thing - I've only ever used cells made naturally in the storyboard - so I had no clue what was going on.  Thanks for the save!

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue fixed with replacing conventional `registercell` line with below line

```
[self.collection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"nibname" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier];
```

Swift 4.2 version:  (thanks Nikolay Suvandzhiev)

```html
self.collection.register(UINib(nibName: "nibname", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)
```

Comment: This helped me ! If you have a XIB for your cell then use this method. I was using auto complete and I landed up using registerClass:forCellWithReuseId: and that caused my views to not load and hence not show up.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Swift 4.2 version: `self.collection.register(UINib(nibName: "nibname", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)`

Answer (score 4):

The mistake is the way how you register the Nib/Xib file (using Swift 5):

use this register method:

```
myCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "myCustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myCustomCell")
```

instead of this:

```
myCollectionView.register(myCustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myCustomCell")
```

Answer (score 1):

I felt like a dummy when I realized my collection view cells were being covered up by my navigation bar. Sooo, make sure your navigation bar (if you have one) isn't covering the collection view cells you're testing with.

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiating a new collection view in your code, but aren't adding the view to the screen. You say you're already using storyboards, my guess is that what you can see is the collection view from your storyboard, which presumably isn't connected to a datasource or delegate? Either that or you're not calling reload on the right collection view.

Either configure your collection view in the storyboard (and set up an outlet to it for anything that must be done in code) or set it up completely in code. At the moment I think you have two collection views.

Answer (score 0):

I made it using Xcode 6.2 storyboard. Hope it helps

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface InfoSecurity : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *tabsCV;

@end

.m
**************

#import "InfoSecurity.h"
#import "TabsCell.h"

@interface InfoSecurity ()<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

@end

@implementation InfoSecurity

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self.tabsCV registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TabsCell"];

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 03;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 01;
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(90, 50);
}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"tabscellID";


    TabsCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.TabTitleLabel.text= @"OPTIONS";

    return cell;

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the collection view cell is black (same color with background, invisible, hidden is no), reloading the visible cells is a work around.